# restore database file from dropbox to local memory

Tags: android, dropbox

I have implemented  a database backup on dropbox, i would like to restore the DB from dropbox to the internal memory (data\data\\database),
 i think is forbidden to write directly, is possible to read by stream the file on dropbox, and open the local file, clear the data inside , and flush the stream into the file?
If yes, anyone have a code for example?

I hope to be clear.
 this is my code...

```
private boolean downloadDropboxFile(String dbPath, File localFile) throws IOException{

    BufferedInputStream br = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bw = null;

    try {
        if (!localFile.exists()) {
            localFile.createNewFile(); //otherwise dropbox client will fail silently
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        DropboxInputStream fd = mApi.getFileStream (dbPath, null);
        br = new BufferedInputStream(fd, buffer.length);
        bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));


        int read;
        while (true) {
            read = br.read(buffer);
            if (read <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //in finally block:
        if (bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Everything is possible. /data/data/packagename/databases/mydatabase.db. what is wrong with your code? It looks ok. Use getDatabaseDir().

Comment: when i use debug for ste-by-step , and I arrive at the line:
DropboxInputStream fd = mApi.getFileStream (dbPath, null);
the prograg jump directly to finally!! why? whitout exception...